# convert JSON to multipart/form-data angular/ionic

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, postman, ionic-native

**When i send POST request form POSTMAN and get correct response**

This is Form-Data Body request of Postman POST.

> ENDPOINT : https://cholas.in/wp-json/digits/v1/send_otp

[image: Success Respond when i request with Form-Data]

**When i send POST request from POSTMAN and get Wrong response**

JSON Body request

```
Content-Type : multipart/form-data;
```

[image: When i send POST request from POSTMAN and get Wrong response]

Content-Type : multipart/form-data; header with json body :

[image: Content-Type : multipart/form-data; header with json body]

**Angular and IONIC code when i send post request**

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    let httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'
        })
    };
  
    
    formData.append('countrycode',this.formSMS.countrycode);
    formData.append('mobileNo',this.formSMS.mobileNo);
    formData.append('type',this.formSMS.type);
    formData.append('whatsapp',this.formSMS.whatsapp);
    // rest data to the form.
    //Object.keys(restObj).forEach(key => {
    //  formData.append(key, restObj[key]);
    //});
    console.log(formData);
    // Send it.
    return this.http.post(Url, formData, httpOptions)
      .toPromise()
      .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        // handle me
      });
```

But i get Wrong Response that i don't want.

[image: angular/ionic wrong response that i don't want]

**NB: OTP Providers Documentation NOTE: The request should be sent as POST Parameters in Body**

What will be the right wey in IONIC/ANGULAR/POSTMAN(JSON Type) to getting right Resonse that i getting as POSTMAN first Screenshot ?

Comment: Any one any idea whare i am getting error in ionic code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to pass httpOptions in post data since You are passsing Form data angular will handle that for you

```
const formData = new FormData();
    let httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'
        })
    };
  
    
    formData.append('countrycode',this.formSMS.countrycode);
    formData.append('mobileNo',this.formSMS.mobileNo);
    formData.append('type',this.formSMS.type);
    formData.append('whatsapp',this.formSMS.whatsapp);
    // rest data to the form.
    //Object.keys(restObj).forEach(key => {
    //  formData.append(key, restObj[key]);
    //});
    console.log(formData);
    // Send it.
    return this.http.post(Url, formData)
      .toPromise()
      .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        // handle me
      });
```

Below stackbliz contains the solution please refer
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-get-examples-f28x9u?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you [Rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5074425/rahul-cv) , this is really awesome, that works fine . But i will also use this in IONIC Native , have you any idea is this same tricks also works in IONIC or not ?

Comment: Yes , This will work in ionic as well. If the answer solved your please mark it as accepted one.